# how I can get full URL of images when using getPageHTML of dokuwiki xmlrpc api

Tags: api, dokuwiki

I want to embed the HTML content of a dokuWiki page inside another web application. The content should be shown as a tooltip popup. But when I use the 'wiki.getPageHTML' api method to get the content, embedded images dont have the full path in their tag.
Like: `<img src="/mywiki/lib/exe/fetch.....">`

Is it possible to get the full image path in HTML code?
E.g.: `<img src="https://testwiki.com/mywiki/lib/exe/fetch....">`

Answer (score -1):

This option do the job: https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:canonical

thx for andi who answered my question [here](https://forum.dokuwiki.org/d/20478-get-full-url-of-images-when-using-getpagehtml-of-xmlrpc-api/3).

Comment: Please consider improving your answer. It could use a better explanation.